# Сделать чтобы скрипт исполнялся с каждым элементом, а не только с первым

Tags: javascript

Как сделать чтобы скрипт исполнялся с каждым элементом textarea, а не только с первым.

Смысл работы скрипта:

Если в textarea есть текст, то делаем insertAdjacentHTML возле этого textarea. Если нету, то пропускаем и работаем со следующим textarea. И так для всех textarea с классом localstoragesave.

```
// Не этот скрипт, следующий
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('localstoragesave');
var elementsParent = document.querySelector("textarea").closest("span");
function checkValidity() {};
for (i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
 (function(element) {
   var id = element.getAttribute('id');
   element.value = localStorage.getItem(id + location.search);
   element.oninput = function() {
     localStorage.setItem(id + location.search, element.value);
     checkValidity();
   };
 })(elements[i]);
}

// Этот скрипт
window.onload = function() {
    if(elements[0].value > "") {
        for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            elementsParent.insertAdjacentHTML('afterEnd', 'В этом textarea есть текст');
        }
    }
};
```

Вот верстка

```
<div class="dots">
    <span class="badge rounded-pill dot dot-1 noted-dot">&ZeroWidthSpace;
        <div class="d-none date2022-10-27">
            <textarea class="localstoragesave form-control rounded-0 border-0 h-100" id="note-2022-10-27"></textarea>
        </div>
    </span>
</div>
<div class="dots">
    <span class="badge rounded-pill dot dot-1 noted-dot">&ZeroWidthSpace;
        <div class="d-none date2022-10-28">
            <textarea class="localstoragesave form-control rounded-0 border-0 h-100" id="note-2022-10-28"></textarea>
        </div>
    </span>
</div>
<div class="dots">
    <span class="badge rounded-pill dot dot-1 noted-dot">&ZeroWidthSpace;
        <div class="d-none date2022-10-29">
            <textarea class="localstoragesave form-control rounded-0 border-0 h-100" id="note-2022-10-29"></textarea>
        </div>
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Используем querySelectorAll вместо  querySelector

```js
const elementsParents = document.querySelectorAll("textarea");
window.onload = function() {
  for (let element of elementsParents) {
    element.closest("div").insertAdjacentHTML('afterEnd', '<span class="badge rounded-pill dot dot-1 noted-dot">&ZeroWidthSpace;Здесь есть текст</span>');
  }
};
```

```html
<div class="dots">
  <div class="d-none date2022-10-28">
    <textarea class="localstoragesave form-control rounded-0 border-0 h-100" id="note-2022-10-28"></textarea>
  </div>
  <span id="dot2-2022-10-28" class="badge rounded-pill dot dot-2 success-dot">&ZeroWidthSpace;0</span>
  <span id="dot2-2022-10-28" class="badge rounded-pill dot dot-3 success-dot">&ZeroWidthSpace;0</span>
</div>
<div class="dots">
  <div class="d-none date2022-10-29">
    <textarea class="localstoragesave form-control rounded-0 border-0 h-100" id="note-2022-10-29"></textarea>
  </div>
  <span id="dot2-2022-10-29" class="badge rounded-pill dot dot-2 success-dot">&ZeroWidthSpace;0</span>
  <span id="dot2-2022-10-29" class="badge rounded-pill dot dot-3 success-dot">&ZeroWidthSpace;0</span>
</div>
<div class="dots">
  <div class="d-none date2022-10-30">
    <textarea class="localstoragesave form-control rounded-0 border-0 h-100" id="note-2022-10-30"></textarea>
  </div>
  <span id="dot2-2022-10-30" class="badge rounded-pill dot dot-2 success-dot">&ZeroWidthSpace;</span>
  <span id="dot2-2022-10-30" class="badge rounded-pill dot dot-3 success-dot">&ZeroWidthSpace;</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Не тот результат скрипта. Наверно я не объяснил смысл его работы. Если в textarea есть текст, то делаем insertAdjacentHTML возле этого textarea. Если нету, то пропускаем и работаем со следующим textarea. И так для всех textarea с классом localstoragesave.

Comment: Хм.. мне  казалось, что вопрос был, как заставить скрипт работать с каждым textarea... В любом случае поправил скрипт.

Comment: Что-то я опять не понял.. Если в textarea есть текст, то делаем insertAdjacentHTML возле этого textarea. - Сейчас в примере все textarea пустые.

Comment: Это наверное у меня проблема с изложением мыслей :) Смотрите, insertAdjacentHTML вставляет примечание что в этой textarea есть текст. Если нет текста, то и не нужно примечания.

Comment: Правильно, сейчас в примере все textarea пустые. Верхний скрипт сохраняет в localStorage то что Вы напишете в textarea. Только, здесь на сайте через "фрагмент" он работать не будет, нужно сохранить в файл. Получается что Вы что-то написали в одно из textarea и возле него появилось примечание.

Answer (score 0):

Ответ дан в англоязычном разделе stackoverflow здесь
https://stackoverflow.com/a/74441791/15935776

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('localstoragesave');

// Not this script. It save textarea value in localStorage
function checkValidity() {};
for (i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
 (function(element) {
   var id = element.getAttribute('id');
   element.value = localStorage.getItem(id + location.search);
   element.oninput = function() {
     localStorage.setItem(id + location.search, element.value);
     const spanEl = element.closest("span");
     if(element.value != "") {
        spanEl.classList.add("noted-dot");
     }
     else{
        spanEl.classList.remove("noted-dot");
     }
     checkValidity();
   };
 })(elements[i]);
}

// This script
window.onload = function() {
for (i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
    if(elements[i].value != "") {
    console.log("log", elements[i].closest("span"))
        elements[i].closest("span").classList.add("noted-dot");
    }
}
};
```